# how to stop the cronjob after the previous success

Tags: shell, cron, sh

am writing a crontab script, which will run on each Saturday for every 15minutes. The idea is to validate an external api status =SUCCESS or not. If its success, then the cronjob for the day should not trigger any more.
Right now am trying with recursion, but I dont think so that is a best solution.
Is there any other solution to achieve this? am using Shell script to invoke api.

Here is the existing snippet:

- Cronjob:

  ```
  */15 * * * 6 validate.sh
  ```
- script:

  ```
  status='curl -X GET "api"' 
  if [[ $status == "SUCCEEDED" ]];then 
      trigger email
  else sleep 180 
      ./validate.sh     
  fi
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `cron` job so it removes the flag file on Friday evening, before the other job starts running:

```
59 23 * * 5 rm .succeeded.txt
```

Then change your script so it aborts if this file exists, and creates it when it succeeds.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

test -e .succeeded.txt && exit
 
if [[ $(curl -X GET "api") == "SUCCEEDED" ]];then 
    trigger email
    touch .succeeded.txt
fi
```

I tried to fix other errors in your script, too, but I had to guess many things. This assumes `"SUCCEEDED"` is the sole output from `curl` when the `GET` works.

Putting the command in a variable is a useless complication which makes your script longer and (very slightly) slower, but in addition, it creates problems of its own when the command contains embedded quotes; see e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

... But of course, presumably you wanted to actually *run* the command. Your attempt would merely check whether the string in the variable was equal to `"SUCEEDED"` which of course it would never be.

Another problem was that you were spawning multiple `validate.sh` jobs, each of which would recurse and retry. You want one or the other, not both.  I went with keeping your schedule and just trying once in each job.

Comment: this works .. but is there any other better option, like killing the cron job if the condition satisfies. Because if by mistake this file gets deleted for any reason, the risk would be high in production

Comment: Killing the cron job seems significantly more risky and brittle. Why would the file be deleted by mistake? Don't put it in a place where people do unrelated things. Maybe give it a better name. The current code creates it in the home directory simply because your example runs in the home directory, but of course, you can put a full path to any location where the user has write access.